# How to link each Jenkins build to its own SonarQube analysis version?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint

I am running a SonarQube - Jenkins integration.

**I need to achieve the following:**

- Link each pipeline build with that respective SonarQube analysis.

i.e

> Build A - Passes Quality Gate
>   Build B - Fails Quality Gate

If I click on the SonarQube link associated with **build A** - It directs to the SonarQube dashboard showing a failure.

If I click on the SonarQube link associated with **build B** - It directs to the SonarQube dashboard showing a success.

**I have tried the following:**

```
sonar.projectVersion = ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
```

This just tells with which analysis version to compare the latest analysis.

How can I achieve a direct link with the SonarQube dashboard and that particular build number in a Jenkins script pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want read Sonar Quality Gate in your Jenkins job ?
Sonar Quality gate will generate a "report-task.txt" file once analysis completed.
Depending on your project size, it might take a while.

Then, using Sonar rest api, you can get json status and use it.

Here is a copy/paste sample I'm using :

```
myEcho('DEBUG', "I want to wait for SONAR completion")

                if (fileExists('target/sonar/report-task.txt')) {
                    //echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'cat target/sonar/report-task.txt')
                    def reportTak = readProperties(file: "target/sonar/report-task.txt")

                    def countLoop = 0
                    def countMax = 10
                    def sonarGateIsDone = false

                    // wait at least 1 second before asking for Sonar feedback
                    sleep(time: 3000, unit: 'MILLISECONDS')
                    while (!sonarGateIsDone && (countLoop <= countMax)) {
                        countLoop++

                        // loop while status is over OR timeout...
                        echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl ${SONAR_URL}api/ce/task?id=${reportTak.ceTaskId} -o target/sonar/output.json")
                        if (fileExists('target/sonar/output.json')) {
                            def outputJson = readJSON(file: 'target/sonar/output.json')
                            if ("${outputJson.task.status}" == 'SUCCESS' || "${outputJson.task.status}" == 'CANCELED' || "${outputJson.task.status}" == 'FAILED') {
                                myEcho('INFO', "Sonar Gate internal analysis finished [${outputJson.task.status}]")
                                if ("${outputJson.task.status}" == 'SUCCESS') {
                                    // internal process done, lets check Gate status
                                    echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl ${SONAR_URL}api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=${outputJson.task.analysisId} -o target/sonar/sonarGate.json")
                                    if (fileExists('target/sonar/sonarGate.json')) {
                                        def sonarGateJson = readJSON(file: 'target/sonar/sonarGate.json')
                                        if ("${sonarGateJson.projectStatus.status}" == 'OK') {
                                            // Gate is OK
                                            myEcho('INFO', "Sonar gate is OK : status=[${sonarGateJson.projectStatus.status}]")
                                            sonarGateIsDone = true
                                        } else {
                                            // Gate is NOK
                                            myEcho('WARN', "Sonar gate is NOK : status=[${sonarGateJson.projectStatus.status}]")
                                            sonarGateIsDone = true
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        // cannot find SonarGate.json ?!
                                        myEcho('FAIL', 'Sonar gate check failed : cannot find [target/sonar/sonarGate.json]')
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    myEcho('WARN', "Sonar gate check is [${outputJson.task.status}]...")
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Sonar internal analysis isnt over, keep on going
                                myEcho('INFO', "Sonar Gate internal analysis still ongoing, wait a little... [${outputJson.task.status}]")
                            }

                        } else {
                            myEcho('FAIL', 'Sonar gate check failed : cannot find [target/sonar/output.json]')
                        }

                        // reaching here might probably be for Sonar to get time to make it...
                        if (!sonarGateIsDone) {
                            sleep(time: 1000, unit: 'MILLISECONDS')
                        }
                    } // while loop

                    if (!sonarGateIsDone) {
                        myEcho('WARN', "Waiting too long for completion... gave up !")
                    }

                } else {
                    myEcho('INFO', "target/sonar/report-task.txt DOES NOT EXISTS")
                }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards